# Abnormal error message with java.util.ArrayList and "Enum"

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax-error

I have a very simple program for a homework assignment, I'm trying to group bills by years and months using a class called "Payment" (terrible name, I know) that I store within an ArrayList (I'm open to suggestions for a better container).

However I get a strange error message from Eclipse (will put at end).

```
public class Payment {
    private double[] Month;
    private int Year;
    private boolean Paid;

    ....
    // A lot of setters, getters, nothing important
}
```

Now I want to create an array list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bill {
    ArrayList<Payment> Money = new ArrayList<Payment>();
    Money. // error -> Money didn't get highlighted, intellisense did not provide 
                      // a list of methods
```

Error reads as follows:

```
Multiple markers at this line:
    Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    Syntax error on token "Money", delete this token
    Syntax error on token "Money", delete this token
    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
```

I have absolutely no idea why this happens. I went in my main file to test this out, it works there, just not here, within the "Bill" class, which is basically empty right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to call some `ArrayList` method on `Money` reference.

Note that, you cannot have statements like that directly inside the class. You need to have some `method` where you can put it.

Here's an example: -

```
public int getListSize() {
    return Money.size();
}
```

If you put `Money.size()` outside all the methods, it will be a compiler error.
: -

```
public class Demo {
    Money.size();  // Compiler Error

    public void getSize() {
        Money.size();   // Ok. Well, I have just added it plain to show it works
                        // Ideally you would return it, or print it.
    }
}
```

However, you can have the call on the RHS, to assign the return value to an int: -

```
public class Demo {
    int size = Money.size();  // Now this is fine
}
```

Comment: But I can still have `private ArrayList<Payment> someName`, right ?

Comment: @Kalec.. Yeah that you can have. That is a declaration, and is allowed.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So I can't have method calls within the body of the class. I feel stupid now since I didn't even intend to use it that way, I just wanted to see what methods ArrayList has and was perplexed by the syntax error

Comment: @Kalec.. Note the last code I posted. You can call methods, provided you are doing it on RHS.

Comment: RHS means Right-Hand-Side ;) the right side of an assignment. Just for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to call a method from the ArrayList `Money` within the body of the class `Bill`. Put the method call into a constructor or method.

And btw try to follow the Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Variable names should be in ´lowerCamelCase`.